# "undefined columns selected" in lapply() call

Tags: r, subset, lapply

> Error in `[.data.frame`(meuse@data, , x) : undefined columns selected

MWE:

```
library(automap)
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) = ~ x+y
lapply(1:1, function (x) {
    automap::autofitVariogram(meuse@data[, x] ~ 1, input_data = meuse)
})
```

Executing `meuse@data[,1]` outside the `lapply`call works fine and returns a numeric vector.

Also `automap::autofitVariogram(meuse@data[, 1] ~ 1, input_data = meuse)` runs fine.

Hence I expected it the problem to be caused by the `lapply` call. However, using another dataset of mine (SpPointsDaFr) does not cause the problem and runs fine.

Looking at the error message more closely, I am not sure if the second "comma" after "meuse@data," is always present in 'subset' error messages?

**Edit:**

Another approach which does not work: Addressing via string (note that I only use `[1:1]` instead of `[1]` for further function use)

```
cols <- names(meuse@data) [1:1]
> lapply(cols, function (x) {
+     automap::autofitVariogram(meuse@data[, x] ~ 1, input_data = meuse)
+ })
```

Comment: Would `lapply(... meuse@data[[x]]~1 ...` work?

Comment: no, returns `Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : no such index at Level 1`

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. Addressing/subsetting the required values of `meuse` before the call of `autofitVariogram` and then putting the object `tmp` in works.

```
lapply(1:1, function (x) {
        tmp <- meuse@data[, x]
        emp.svgm <- automap::autofitVariogram(tmp ~ 1, meuse)
})
```

The error when trying to subset inside the function call is still open for discussion though.